# Display several vtk render windows at the same time

Tags: python, python-2.7, rendering, vtk, itk

I am working with vtk for python. I am displaying some vtk meshes using this code:

```
def DisplayVTKMesh(mesh):
    mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
    mapper.SetInputData(mesh)
    actor = vtk.vtkActor()
    actor.SetMapper(mapper)
    actor.GetProperty().SetInterpolationToPhong()
    actor.GetProperty().SetAmbient(0.2)
    actor.GetProperty().SetDiffuse(0.7)
    actor.GetProperty().SetSpecular(0.6)
    actor.GetProperty().SetSpecularPower(100)
    actor.GetProperty().SetColor(0.8,0.8,1)
    ren1 = vtk.vtkRenderer()
    ren1.AddActor(actor)
    ren1.SetBackground(1, 1, 1)
    renWin = vtk.vtkRenderWindow()
    renWin.AddRenderer(ren1)
    renWin.SetSize(300, 300)
    iren = vtk.vtkRenderWindowInteractor()
    iren.SetRenderWindow(renWin)
    style = vtk.vtkInteractorStyleTrackballCamera()
    iren.SetInteractorStyle(style)
    iren.Initialize()
    iren.Start()
```

I am loading different meshes and calling the function above in a for loop , because I want to have one window for every mesh.
The problem is that it shows one volume, and it waits until I close the window to display the next one.
How can I display several windows at the same time instead of having one window at a time and having to close it to display the next one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the multiprocessing module, running one process per window.